# List a server's available WMI Performance data classes

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, perfmon

How can I get a list of all WMI performance counters classes on a given server, to use in scripts for monitoring purposes.

I know one can use the performance monitor, but the classes displayed don't match the name of those available via WMI `PerfFormattedData` classes.

The `Get-Counters` offer some advantages over the `Get-CimInstance` commandlet, such as passing an array of counters, but the returned counters are not script friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Using powershell is pretty easy and quick with that command:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData  | Select-Object __CLASS | Sort-Object -Unique -Property __CLASS | format-list
```

Or Redirect to a file:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData  | Select-Object __CLASS | Sort-Object -Unique -Property __CLASS | format-list *> .\Win32_PerfFormattedData_class_list.txt
```

and then one can discover the fields of an individual class:

```
PS C:\Users\user1> Get-CimInstance Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory

AvailableBytes                       : 6186450944
AvailableKBytes                      : 6041456
AvailableMBytes                      : 5899
CacheBytes                           : 426688512
CacheBytesPeak                       : 1207418880
CacheFaultsPersec                    : 3
CommitLimit                          : 157792387072
CommittedBytes                       : 135447302144
DemandZeroFaultsPersec               : 305
FreeAndZeroPageListBytes             : 3529670656
FreeSystemPageTableEntries           : 16423182
```